# Are there gotchas when copying a base class reference to child class? (downcasting)

Tags: c#, oop

I have `List<Character> citizens`.
Citizens have various properties, most important are:

```
public string firstname;
public Dictionary<Character, Relationship> relationships { get; set; }
...
```

Citizens can become things **after they are created**, like a `Trader : Character`.
So in my list of citizens I want to replace a reference to a Character with one to a Trader.

I read and understand the answers about downcasting.  So I will do the constructor approach:

```
public Trader(Character c)
{
    firstname = c.firstname;
    relationships = c.relationships;
    ...         
}
```

And then I want to replace the reference to the old Character and use this fancy new Trader:

```
citizens.Remove(old);
citizens.Add(fancyTrader);
```

What concerns me is references to the relationship dictionary, does that not just cause the old `Character` object to hang around forever, meaning there are two copies of this guy in memory and the old one will never be garbage collected away?

I'm concerned because I have tens of thousands of these citizens.

Comment: This classification could also be a property of a citizen instead of type of citizen.  If you are converting types by cloning you can end up working in stale references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around this is to use composition instead inheritance.  Consider abstracting your `Character` information in to multiple parts.  The `Character` class holds the name data and relationships, while a `Role` class holds their "job".  `Trader` would be a subclass of `Role`, and `Character` would have a property on it for that citizen's role (or even a list of roles if they can have more than one.

This gives you a  lot of flexibility, and also prevents your references from getting tangled up when a character changes roles.

Comment: I was afraid this may be the answer. :-( It's a significant architectural change because most of my codebase uses `Character`. I think i'll try this through Interfaces first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *could* have a memory leak in this scenario, but if you are at all careful about cleaning up after yourself you'll be fine (and this has nothing to do with downcasting).

The primary "gotchas" of downcasting are attempting it against a type that isn't actually what you are casting to, which is a runtime error (not ideal). With your approach, you need to make sure you understand that you are doing a *shallow* copy and the potential bugs that raises as well.

I would run the program for a while with a profiler, make sure you aren't having an ever-increasing number of references and use that to see if you have a problem. Having a "Dispose" method on your `Citizen` that cleans up the relationships dictionary when the object is no longer needed would go a long way towards solving any such issues.